# extjs4 : hide/show pictures of a tab panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a tab panel with two tabs.
I wish that both tabs would contain images alongside their text, yet the image on each tab would be shown only when the tab is clicked, otherwise it won't be shown (or replaced).

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

> You could probably do it by some css trick.For example,try this.

```
 Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        id: 'tabPanel',
        activeCls: 'activeTabCls',
        renderTo: document.body,
        items: [{
            title: 'Foo',
        }, {
            title: 'Bar'
        }]

    });
```

Your **CSS** could be something like:

```
.activeTabCls .x-tab-default-top-active{
   background-image: url(http://sencha.com/favicon.icon)!important;
   background-position-y: 4px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
}
```

Note : Not Tested.Some modifications could be needed.